# secure register form from preventing html injection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm creating an app that has 2 types of users (employer, jobseeker), but I have a security issue (html injection), in my form I have a hidden field that calls "account_type_id" where I in the AuthController check the type of account, and depending of the account type I validate or create this type of user data.

At first I wanted to use in the same controller the registration of different users, but now I'm not quite sure how I could check in the AuthController which type of user is being register, the only difference I notice in both of them is that they use different routes where each one use different register forms.

How could I check which type of user being register without using hidden fields on the form?

Example code:

```
AuthController:

protected function validator(array $data)
    {

        $accountType = AccountType::find($data['account_type_id']);


        if($accountType->name === "employer"){
            return Validator::make($data, [
                //employer validation
            ]);
        }else{
            return Validator::make($data, [
     //candidate validation
                ...
            ]);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {

        // Check type of account
        $accountType = AccountType::find($data['account_type_id']);


        if($accountType->name === "employer"){

            //employer create


        }else{

            //Candidate user create

        }


        return $user;
    }
```

Comment: Can anyone sign up as an employer or jobseeker on your app? If yes, then these checks are irrelevant / not needed

Comment: Could you post the forms to 2 seperate routes that call the same register method this way you could set a variable to distinguish the user type in your controller?

Comment: u can't distinguish them unless you have session or something unique to that user, in any case user will be selecting what he wanted, better give them a checkbox to choose or use the route path detect who is who.